# what does Area(A) in Randles-sevcik equation refer to? geometrical area of electrode or electrochemical active surface area/

Tags: electrochemistry, experimental-chemistry

In the [Randles-Sevcik equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randles%E2%80%93Sevcik_equation),

> $$i_p = 0.4463 \ nFAC \left(\frac{nFvD}{RT}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

we have an area $A$ in the formula. is this the electrochemically active area or geometrical area? I have seen in an article that they consider $A$ as both the geometrical area of the electrode and the electrochemical area. which one is true?

Comment: It is area in contact with the solution.

Comment: @EdV: I think it is also tacitly assumed that we are talking about one face of the electrode? In conductometry electrodes, one face is always buried or hidden so the area is one face of the electrode but what about CV?

Comment: @EdV Thanks. Looks great. I have seen the Hg drop ones but not the solid electrodes you have.

Comment: If I recall correctly, the area of electrode is determined with ferrocynanide standards, right? I have seen glassy carbon but I am sure carbon is bad boy in terms of reproducibility. The guy who invented carbon electrodes (Ralph Adams) had contaminated his lab air with carbon paritculates so badly that instrument would spark and die. Carbon was everywhere.